# Combine "resourceTimeline" with "dayGridYear"

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

in current angular project I need to show past and future events within a year back and year ahead, but will be also satisfied within a year. Is it possible to combine the view type "resourceTimeline" with "dayGridYear", which came in version 6.1?

Ideally, the user would have a view of the "resourceTimeline" type, while the date range is a year back and a year ahead. I will also be satisfied with the scope in a given year if the above is impossible. "resourceTimeline" is very important because there is a lot of work on events. Below current configuration:

```
private getFullCalendarOptions(): CalendarOptions {
    return {
      initialView: FullcalendarViewTemplates.ResourceTimelineMonth,
      schedulerLicenseKey: environment.fullCalendarLicenceKey,
      plugins: [resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin],
      firstDay: 1,
      resourceAreaWidth: '20rem',
      height: 500,
      selectable: true,
      editable: true,
      rerenderDelay: null,
      droppable: true,
      nowIndicator: true,
      resourceOrder: 'full_name',
      displayEventTime: false,
      dragScroll: true,
      eventAllow: someMethod...,
      locale: someMethod...,
      views: {
        [FullcalendarViewTemplates.ResourceTimelineMonth]: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { months: 1 },
          nowIndicator: false,
          slotLabelFormat: {
            weekday: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
          },
        },
      },
      resourceAreaColumns: [...]
   }
```

Comment: You can set a custom duration on the timeline view so it displays any period of time. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration . For even more control, check out the visibleRange setting too